# Can't import tensorflow when run script from terminal, even though tensorflow works in jupyter notebook and terminal

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-import, importerror, dllimport

TLDR: When I write a small script named toy_model.py and attempt to run it from the command line with

```
py toy_model.py
```

I get an error message complaining about loading tensorflow.

However, I am able to use import and use tensorflow in many other settings without any problem, such as

- In a jupyter notebook
- when I import toy_model.py into a jupyter notebook
- when I use python from the command line

I have tried many recommended solutions (downloading Spyder in the Anaconda Navigator virtual environment I am using, switching from tensorflow 2.1.0 to tensorflow 2.0.0, downloading microsoft visual studio), and none have been succesful.

I would be grateful for any assistance or insight into this problem, which I will describe in more detail below.

---

I use Anaconda Navigator to code in Python. In Anaconda Navigator, I prepared an environment with the name `updated_tensorflow`. I used Anaconda's package manager to download tensorflow 2.0.0 and keras 2.3.1 into this environment.

I prepared a jupyter notebook named `test1.ipynb` with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(10,))])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss= 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', #should be 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' b/c one-hot encoded
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.predict([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9,10]])
```

When I run `test1.ipynb` from the environment `updated_tensorflow`, there are no problems.

In the terminal I entered the environment `updated_tensorflow`, and began using python by typing `python` in the command line. I entered the same code as in `test1.ipynb` and had no problems.

I create a file with the name `toy_model.py` that contained the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(10,))])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss= 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', #should be 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' b/c one-hot encoded
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then, I created another jupyter notebook in the same directory as `toy_model1.py` with the name `test2.ipynb` and the following code:

```
from toy_model1 import *
model.predict([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9,10]])
```

This cell ran with no problems.

Finally, in this same directory, I produced a small file with the name `toy_model.py` which contained the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(10,))])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss= 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', #should be 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' b/c one-hot encoded
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.predict([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9,10]])
```

Then in my terminal, still in the environment `updated_tensorflow`,  I moved to the directory containing `toy_model.py` and attempted to run it with

```
py toy_model.py
```

I got the following message that indicated I could not import tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toy_model.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Some of the advice I have followed in my unsuccessful efforts to fix this problem includes:

- making sure pip and setup tools are updated
- uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow and keras using pip
- uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow and keras using conda
- switching from tensorflow 2.1.0 to tensorflow to 2.0.0
- installing tensorflow and keras on my base anaconda environment
- installing tensorflow and keras on my machine
- downloading Spyder in my `updated_tensorflow` environment
- downloading Microsoft visual studios
  None have been successful.

I would be very grateful for any assistance in understanding and fixing whatever error I am making. It would be so nice if I could use run .py files from my terminal instead of using python exclusively in Jupyter notebooks!

Even a hint as to what the error message means would be helpful: I do not properly understand what a DLL even is.

Comment: The error in question is produced within Spyder environment? Or standalone Python interpreter? If the former, can you try to import tensorflow from Python interpreter, e.g. `python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"`? My suspicion is that Spyder is messing your environment variables.

Comment: Yes @LukaszTracewski it is just from my standalone Python interpreter, I had this problem even before I downloaded Spyder (and I am not even using Spyder in this case). I will follow up on your suggestion and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like, by invoking `python`, you are not getting the specific python installation that has tensorflow (or tensorflow in that installation is broken). By default, invoking `python` will give you the system default (it's the first one in the environment path, so that's the first hit).

I would advise identifying exactly which python interpreter your notebook is using and calling that one specifically by saying

```
/path/to/notebook/interpreter/python toy_model.py
```

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. Strangely, `python toy_model.py` works perfectly, even though `py toy_model.py` gives the errors I documented in my first post. Odd! Do you know why there might be this difference in behavior?

Comment: What happens if you run `$ alias py` or `$ where py` in your shell? That should tell you whether `py` is calling the same python interpreter that you think it is.

Comment: As @LoraJohns points out, I think it's probably an aliasing issue. This means that when you invoke "py", your environment understands that as /path/to/some/python which might not be the system default, while "python" goes for the system default. The issue you are experiencing is quite common, so I expect that some variation of calling the wrong python is what's happening here.

Comment: Oh, thank you !!! I am trying to run my py file through the terminal, all I needed to do is show the correct path of the interpreter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the latest supported Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did download Microsoft Visual Studios 2019 which is what comes up when I google latest Microsoft Visual C++, and this attempt did not fix my problem.